# "int_list_validator" is not working in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I made the following Django form.

```
from django.core.validators import int_list_validator

class RoomForm(forms. Form):
    room_numbers = forms.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], required=False, max_length=4000)
```

In this form even if I submit a string like 'hello' the form gets submitted. I mean I can get the value 'hello' in views.py. I don't understand why because "int_list_validator" should not allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunate naming: `int_list_validator` is not a validator but a helper function that creates one.

`validate_comma_separated_integer_list` is a validator, created by calling `int_list_validator` with a more suitable message than the default `_("Enter a valid value.")`:

> ```py
> validate_comma_separated_integer_list = int_list_validator(
>     message=_("Enter only digits separated by commas."),
> )
> ```

Usage:

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import int_list_validator, validate_comma_separated_integer_list


# room_numbers = forms.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], required=False, max_length=4000)
room_numbers = forms.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator()], required=False, max_length=4000)

# Or
room_numbers = forms.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], required=False, max_length=4000)
```